# Elastic queries available in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server-2017

Are elastic queries available in SQL Server 2017?

Can see them documented for Azure SQL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview

but nothing for SQL Server. My assumption is that it's not available.

Answer (score 1):

As the doc says its still in preview with [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview#preview-limitations). So no, sql server 2017 on premise does not have that feature as of now.

Once it is in GA, it *might* be available in sql server (possibly with a Service pack or in newer version of sql server).

Other features like Query Store and adaptive join, etc were first avilable in Azure and then they got into onpremise SQL Serve, so I believe if a feature is featured in Azure, it will eventually get into onpremise sql server may be through a service pack or new version of the software.

Comment: From conversations with Microsoft folks, nearly every new feature is in Azure first, then it trickles down to the on-premise packages.  But as you say, no guarantees on if, when *or* feature limitations.